# Help with is_page() and calling css for specific pages in a Child Theme

Tags: functions, css, child-theme

I'm building a child theme of Newspaper 7, and I'm trying to call a specific stylesheet for certain pages, however is_page() isn't working for me. What should I change in my code to be able to do what I'm trying to do?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 1001);
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('td-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', TD_THEME_VERSION . 'c' , 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style('td-theme-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('td-theme'), TD_THEME_VERSION . 'c', 'all' );

if( is_page( array( 'about-me', 'contact', 'social-media'))) {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'td-theme-child', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style2.css'. 'c', 'all' );
}

}
```

Comment: The first thing that jumps out is there are two stylesheets with the same slug. Try changing the name of the slug on the one wrapped in the `is_page()` conditional to something unique. Also `'/style2.css'. 'c',` looks like a typo to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_register_style` is used to register the stylesheet for later use. So, you can register it early and later call it just specifying it's first parameter.

In this case you are registering and enqueueing the stylesheet `td-theme-child`, which file is `style.css`. After that, if the conditional passes, you are registering and enqueueing the stylesheet `td-theme-child`, which file is `style2.css`... but, WP already sent the `td-theme-child`, so the `style2.css` will never hit the browser.

So, in short, just change the first parameter of your style2.css enqueue line:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'td-theme-child2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style2.css'. 'c', 'all' );
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked! Thank you for helping and explaining.